# Заполнить массив или список или переменную

Tags: javascript, html

Заполнить массив или список или переменную (ну тогда уже сложить все элементы) данными из `input` которые имеют одинаковые `id` или `class` или `name`

```js
function CreateAmountElement() {
  var amountinputneed = document.getElementById('amountinp').value
  for (i = 0; i != amountinputneed; i++) {
    var firstform = document.getElementById('frm');
    var rates = document.createElement('input');
    var index = document.createElement('input');
    var label1 = document.createElement("label");
    var label2 = document.createElement("label");
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    label2.innerHTML = "   Index -";
    label1.innerHTML = "Number -";
    rates.type = "number";
    rates.min = 2
    rates.max = 5
    rates.id = "288"
    rates.name = "arabama"
    index.type = "number";
    index.min = 1
    index.max = 5
    index.id = "882"
    firstform.appendChild(label1);
    firstform.appendChild(br);
    firstform.appendChild(rates);
    firstform.appendChild(br);
    firstform.appendChild(label2);
    firstform.appendChild(br);
    firstform.appendChild(index);
    firstform.appendChild(br);
  }
  document.getElementById('allah').remove()
}

function state() {
  alert(document.getElementByName("arabama").value)
  alert(document.getElementById("288").value)
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="frm" name="firstform">
  <label for="amountInpt">Сколько у вас оценок</label>
  <input type="number" name="amountInp12" max="40" min="3" id="amountinp"> </br>

  <input type="button" id="allah" value='Добавить поля для оценок' onclick="CreateAmountElement()">
  <input type="button" id="calc" value="Подсчитать" onclick="state()" width="0"> </br>
</form>
```

Comment: Что значит "все элементы InputS"? А "числовые элементы"? Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Все input с одинаковыми атрибутами "name" "class" "id" любого из них
А потом перевести их в числа если это нужно ну я про parseInt()

Comment: Вам нужно сложить все инпаты у которых одинаковый class или name (id не катит - он уникален). Я верно понял? а если в инпате не число а слово?

Comment: Да правильно поняли

Answer (score 0):

Получает значение у форм с одинаковым name, складывает значения и сохраняет в переменную **all_count**

```js
$("input[name=uname]").each(function() {
  var int = Number($(this).attr('value'));
  var all_count = Number($('#all_count').text());
  $('#all_count').text(int + all_count);
});

var all_count = Number($('#all_count').text());
console.log(all_count)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="uname" value="1">
<input type="text" name="uname" value="1">
<input type="text" name="uname" value="1">
<input type="text" name="uname" value="1">

<span id="all_count"></span>
```

Comment: Как то без jquare можно обойтись ? нехотелось бы начинать разбираться в нем пока должным образом не выучил сам javascript

Comment: Увы, я работаю в основном только с JQuery. Ну структура работы, я думаю, вам понятна. Поищите в Google аналогичные методы для JS

Comment: Хорошо , все равно спасибо за ответ !